# qsub: requesting a job array from within a qsub session

Tags: cluster-computing, qsub, torque

I have a matlab script that processes a large amount of data using torque job arrays.

The server that I SSH into lacks the memory to load the data in the first place, so I need to request the compute node resources as a torque job, as follows:

```
qsub -I -V -l nodes=1:ppn=1,walltime=12:00:00,vmem=80G
```

However, when I now run the matlab script I am unable to submit torque job array requests. The error I am getting is as follows:

```
qsub: submit error (Job rejected by all possible destinations (check syntax, queue resources, ...))
```

The job array request given was:

```
qsub -t 1-$1 -l vmem=16G -l nodes=1:ppn=1,walltime=48:00:00 -v batchID=$2,batchDir=$3,funcName=$4 -e $5 -o $6 $HOME/scripts/job.sh
```

This command works fine outside of a qsub session, and the above error is not transient, so it appears that I cannot submit a request for a torque job array from within a qsub session.

How do I obtain the necessary memory resources from the compute nodes while also being able to submit requests for torque job arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cluster may not allow you to submit jobs from nodes in the cluster. You may be able to ask the admin to change this behavior or you can ssh to the head from within your first job and run the qsub there.

```
ssh head "qsub -t .........."
```

Comment: Thanks Chuck -- ssh was the obvious solution I somehow overlooked :-)